# How to count by using linq (the result has to be an IQueryable)?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to have a list of employees, who are ill more than x times. How do you do that?

Example:
**EmpId, Name, Date**
1, John, 1/4/2016
2, Peter, 1/7/2016
3, Max, 1/14/2016
5, Jack, 1/22/2016
1, John, 2/2/2016
3, Max, 2/9/2016
2, Peter, 2/14/2016
3, Max, 3/1/2016
1, John, 3/4/2016
4, Simon, 3/9/2016

People who 3 times or more are ill.

The result is than:
**EmpId, Name, Date**
1, John, 1/4/2016
3, Max, 2/9/2016

**SQL**

```
select EmpId, count(MyId) from MyTable group by EmpId
```

**CODE**

```
private IQueryable<MyTable> MyQuery(SelectParams selectParams)
{
query = db.MyTables.Where(mt => mt.Active);

if (selectParams.MinXIll > 0)
query = query.GroupBy(sb => sb.EmpId).Where(sb => sb.Count() >= selectParams.MinXIll);

return query;
}
```

Comment: where is the property that shows whether the employee is ill? Is it `mt.Active` ? with the posted code I find it difficult to grasp the entire value organisation

Comment: A count cannot be IQuerable. It has either to be Count (int) or IQuerable or just materialise it to a List Or Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        query = from q1 in query
                from q2 in (query.GroupBy(sb => sb.EmpId)
                                 .Select(i => new { EmpId = i.Key, EmpCount = i.Count() })
                                 .Where(i => i.EmpCount >= selectParams.MinXIll)
                        ) on q1.EmpId equals q2.EmpId
                select q1;
```

or this one

```
        query = from q1 in query
                where
                    (query.GroupBy(sb => sb.EmpId)
                          .Select(i => new { EmpId = i.Key, EmpCount = i.Count() })
                          .Where(i => i.EmpCount >= selectParams.MinXIll)
                          .Select(i => i.EmpId)
                     ).Contains(q1.EmpId)
                select q1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()` if you want to return list from your first query. The list can be filtered further using LINQ:

```
// get all active employees
// assume active field is boolean
List<MyTable> list = db.MyTables.Where(mt => mt.Active == true).ToList();

if (selectParams.MinXIll > 0)
{
    // filter result list to create another list contains proper data
    // assume TotalIll is your key value to determine how many illness on an employee
    var result = list.GroupBy(sb => sb.EmpId).Where(sb => sb.TotalIll >= selectParams.MinXIll).Select(sb => sb.EmpId, sb.MyId.Count()).ToList();
}
```

Hope this may helpful, CMIIW.